# Ruby Regex: Rejecting whole words

Tags: ruby, regex

I know that in Regex, you can reject lists of symbols, such as `[^abc]`. I'd like to reject upon seeing an entire word in the middle of my input.

To be more precise, I'd like to reject "print <Anything except "all">".
A few examples:

```
print all - match
frokenfooster - no match
print all nomnom - no match
print bollocks - no match
print allpies - no match
```

Comment: I feel as though "I'd like to match" and the examples you've provided are a contradiction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for a [negative look-ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=negative+look+ahead+%5Bregex%5D+%5Bruby%5D). (*ref.* [using look-ahead and look-behind](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444))

```
(?!exclude)
```

Would disqualify the word "exclude" in the pattern.

Comment: @Mike: p.s. I think you're looking for `^print ((?!all$).*)$` ;-)

Comment: Missed the anchors. Seems bullet-proof now. :)

Comment: Won't it also disqualify "excluded" if it's in the middle of a line?

Comment: @theTinMan: Yes, that's why you have to encapsulate it.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions support a word-break `\b`.

Searching for the existence of the word "all" in a string is as simple as:

```
>> 'the word "all"'[/\ball\b/] #=> "all"
>> 'the word "ball"'[/\ball\b/] #=> nil
>> 'all of the words'[/\ball\b/] #=> "all"
>> 'we had a ball'[/\ball\b/] #=> nil
>> 'not ball but all'[/\ball\b/] #=> "all"
```

Note, it didn't take anchoring it to the start or end of a string, because `\b` recognizes the start and end of the string as word boundaries also.

Comment: I didn't know that - that's really handy.